# Calling the function pointed by a Pointer-to-Member-Function from within a struct

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a class `Test` with a peculiar data structure.
A member of class `Test` is a `std::map` where the key is a `std::string` and the mapped value is a `struct` defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  void (Test::*f) (void) const;
} pmf_t;
```

Initialization of the map is OK. The problem is when I am trying to call the function pointed. I made up a toy example reproducing the problem. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Test;
typedef void (Test::*F) (void) const;
typedef struct {
  F f;
} pmf_t;


class Test
{
public:
  Test () {
    pmf_t pmf = {
      &Test::Func
    };
    m["key"] = pmf;
  }
  void Func (void) const {
    cout << "test" << endl;
  }
  void CallFunc (void) {
    std::map<std::string, pmf_t>::iterator it = m.begin ();
    ((*it).second.*f) (); // offending line
  }

  std::map<std::string, pmf_t> m;
};


int main ()
{

  Test t;
  t.CallFunc ();

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Jir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the `pmf_t` type is `f`, so the first change is to remove the `*` to get `second.f`. That gives you a pointer-to-member value. To *use* a pointer-to-member, you need an instance. The only one you have available of the correct type is `this`, so use it with the `->*` operator:

```
(this->*it->second.f)();
```

You need parentheses around the whole thing, or else the compiler thinks you're trying to call `it->second.f()` (which isn't allowed) and then applying the result to `->*`.

Comment: Thorough explanation, thanks. I wouldn't have ever thought to prepend `this` to the iterator.

Comment: You're not prepending it to the iterator; you're prepending it to the pointer-to-member expression. (The `->` and `.` operators bind more tightly than `->*`; here's a fully parenthesized version: `(this->*((it->second).f))()`.

Answer (score 3):

The offending line is trying to call a member function without any object to call it on. If the intention is to call it for the `this` object, I believe the call should look like

```
( this->* ((*it).second.f) )();
```

Where `this->*` is the syntax for dereferencing a pointer-to-member for the current object. `((*it).second.f)` is the pointer retrieved from the map, and `()` is the call operator for actually calling the function.

This is perhaps good as an exercise, but otherwise of limited use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to check out the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.6) on this one.  The syntax is apparently pretty tricky to get right (they actually recommend using a macro).

Comment: I've edited the example using the `typedef` as you suggested. However, I still cannot figure out how to call that function. Thanks for the input anyway!

Comment: @Rob, whoops, I linked one entry too early.  The OP actually wants the *next* FAQ, which suggests using a macro to call the function.  I've updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(this->*((*it).second.f)) ();
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late for this question but, the seemingly complex synatax can be break down to two simple lines so it looks pretty clear:

```
void CallFunc (void) 
{
     pmf_t t = m["key"]; //1>get the data from key
    (this->*t.f)();      //2>standard procedure to call pointer to member function
}
```

Comment: Well, this favors the readability. I wonder if creating the local variable `t` is a threat to performance.

Comment: I don't think this extra line is too much of a performance drag in general and yet it has increased the readability quite a lot. This way the project can be better maintained so I would favor this one personally unless you telling me this function is a at a critical performance bottleneck...